# how to define a class on framework(aosp)

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to define my class on frameworks/base/core, and use it as common library.
So what I did was adding a java class file 'MyTime.java' on frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/format folder. However, when I try to import the class, error 'cannot find symbol' occurred.

The code of MyTime class is like below.

```
package android.text.format;
...
public class MyTime {
    ...
}
```

I can't use this class, and tried for days, but still have not found the solution.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This sounds like a bad idea, you are creating a fork of the Android API.
2. Did you run

   ```
   make update-api
   make sdk
   ```

   to update `frameworks/base/api/*.txt` and rebuild `framework.jar`? If not, it will not be visible to users.
3. Repeating 1. Please add to a separate library, not the base framework.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the suggestion. It seems another permission or setting is needed to define a custom class on framework.